# Copy row if value of one cell is "x"; and, auto-hide blanks

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy a row, columns A-J, representing a person and associated info, when column J is filled.  I'd fill it with either w, x, y or z based on the reason people are away, and I'd like the row (A-J) copied to another sheet as soon as J is filled.

Here's a screenshot with both Excel documents.  Please ignore the "Reason" column  in the Pers sheet - I know it could be used, but my production one doesn't have this column, and will not.  I just used it to illustrate for you guys.

[image]

[image]

That other sheet (Main) has headers, as you can see, for each reason why people would be away.  This one would permanently be displayed on a big-screen TV.  So, what I'm trying to do is :

1. Copy the rows to Main as soon as the "Departed?" row is filled in Pers;
2. Make sure those rows go into the proper category, in the first blank row;
3. Ensure each category remains collapsible.

You can see I've tried using the If function (syntax in screenshot).  That worked OK, but :

1. Left blanks;
2. Biggest one : only worked row-for-row!  (Also the cause of reason #1, I suppose...)  Past row 11, nothing.  Not too sure what to do about that...?

Hope this is somewhat clear?  =)  Let me know if you have any questions - thanks for your help!

Comment: Take a look at the Worksheet_Change Event, it will be able to detect if you write in the H colunm, and then copy that row to the Main Sheet.

Comment: Are you sure that the Pivot is not a good solution for you???
If I see your screenshots I think will be an interesting way

Comment: I don't know much about VBA, but I will look at the Worksheet_Change event.  I'll do some digging.  Pivot tables - good idea!  I'll also look at that, thanks.  Only thing is, I wish I would update automatically...